# .NET UserControl for CSS columns?

Tags: .net, css, user-controls

Are there any .NET Controls out there to help with CSS layout and make it nice and easy to quickly make changes - possibly dynamically.

**Update:**

I've pretty much give up on this idea as I've researched more about CSS best practices.

I've decided to use Yahoo YUI's reset css and grids css to get layouts that can be more easily changed and have been fully tested on all A-Grade browsers.

[Main link to grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) | [Example page](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/grids/) | [Example with fixed column width](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/grids/grids-t5.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I have used in the past is a commercial control from [telerik](http://www.telerik.com) called [RadSplitter](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/splitter.aspx). It doesn't produce CSS layouts, but allows you to divide a page into as many areas as you want. These areas can even be resized or collapsed/expanded.